# Getting error on Instance fields aren't final in flutter

Tags: mysql, flutter, dart

I try to pass the data from the page of fetch product list to product detail, but I am getting an error of

> This class (or a class that this class inherits from) is marked as '@immutable', but one or more of its instance fields aren't final: ProdukGapo.list, ProdukGapo.index

How should I fix it?

The product list code:

```
class ItemList extends StatelessWidget {

  final List list;
  ItemList({this.list});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(    
        height: 200,
        child: ListView.builder(
           itemCount: list==null ? 0 : list.length,
           itemBuilder: (context, i){
            return new GestureDetector(
              onTap: ()=>MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (BuildContext context)=>  ProdukGapo(list: list, index: i,)
              ) ,
              child: new Card(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text(list[i]["product_name"]),
                    leading: Icon(Icons.widgets),
                    subtitle: Text("Price RM : ${list[i]["product_price"]}"),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The product detail code on the error part:

```
class ProdukGapo extends StatefulWidget {
  List list;
  int index;
  ProdukGapo({this.index,this.list});
  @override
  _ProdukGapoState createState() => _ProdukGapoState();
}
```

---

The class that I am being used to call into this class is

```
class ProdukGapo extends StatefulWidget {
  List list;
  int index;
  ProdukGapo({this.index,this.list});
  @override
  _ProdukGapoState createState() => _ProdukGapoState();}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  class ProdukGapo extends StatefulWidget {
      final List list;
      final int index;
      ProdukGapo({Key key, this.list, this.index}) : super(key: key);
    @override
    _ProdukGapoState createState() => _ProdukGapoState();
  }
```

And access the parameters like this => **widget.list & widget.index**

try this

Answer (score 1):

Add a constant constructor on your widget

```
class BottomCardState extends StatefulWidget {
  final int _value;
  final String title;
  const BottomCardState(this._value,this.title)

  @override
  _BottomCardStateState createState() => _BottomCardStateState();
}
```

Comment: can you explain a little a bit more? i am not getting any near to the solution..

Comment: I have updated the solution which you need to change in your stateful class. Basically you need to make the variable final in the core class and update their state in state-class as "widget.field-name". Hope this will clear your doubts